# Why does NA in the middle of a geom_line not always break the line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, na

My question is related to this issue:

[Create a line plot using categorical data and not connecting the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505478/creating-a-line-plot-using-categorical-data-and-not-connecting-the-lines-in-ggpl)

Here is the example from the linked question:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 
                 y = c('a', 'a', NA, 'a', 'a'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

A continuous line is drawn, although `df$y` contains `NA`:

```
is.na(df$y)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I am confused because in the help for `geom_line()` under **Missing value handling** it says that:

> geom_path(), geom_line(), and geom_step handle NA as follows:
>
> If an NA occurs in the middle of a line, it breaks the line. No warning is shown, regardless of whether na.rm is TRUE or FALSE.

Can anyone explain to me why this does not work for the categorical data in the example above?

From trying around I guess it has something to do with the `group` part, but I really do not understand how this works. Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit:**
Unlike I assumed, it does not really matter if the data is categorical or numerical. See:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(x)), y = as.numeric(as.factor(y)), group = as.numeric(as.factor(y)))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

This only removes the `NA` *point*, but keeps drawing the line over the break. Indeed, the critical point is the grouping, which is not required for numerical data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(x)), y = as.numeric(as.factor(y)))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

See comments below.

Comment: There are no NA in the data used to create that particular line plot. Please give a __reproducible example__.

Comment: To expand on Edwards comment: The code in the answer you linked uses `na.omit() %>%                              # Drop NA cases so they're not plotted` to explicitly remove rows with `NA` **before** calling `ggplot`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was referring to the code in the linked question, not the answer. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: The `y` variable is being used as the grouping variable, not the data to plot, which has no NA. So your guess that "it" has something to do with the grouping variable was correct. :)

Comment: @Edward: Thank you for your answer! Indeed geom_line _does_ use the `y` variable for plotting because it determines the *position* of the line (that's why `y` is a required aesthetic). But I get what you are saying about the grouping. I think I was confused because I forgot that `geom_line`draws a line **after** clustering it by group, and that, of course, `group`ed data will not consider anything outside the group (like data in other groups, or, in this case, NA’s).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed interesting that it works differently for continuous and categorical data, but it kind of makes sense, given the different nature of those data.

A way around it, without using `rle`, can be factorising and using the factor levels for plotting. You can then change the label with `scale`

[User Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7514527/edward) is right with their comment - grouping is very relevant. Here I used `group = 1`

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 
                 y = c('a', 'a', NA, 'a', 'a'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = as.numeric(as.factor(y)), group = 1)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1, labels = 'a')
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a very clean solution given the stated data set. Of course, it probably only works when there is a single `y` value (not *a* and *b*, for example)?

Comment: @Rafor That seems true. In this case, [the given answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60505874/7941188) is helping indeed